# Rerun pipe for observable when condition changes (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a table that I am filtering based on a user inputted field, and the source of that table is an observable made from a BehaviorSubject. Here's the setup:

```
class Component {
    //filled with a http call to a webservice
    private subject$ = new BehaviorSubject([])
    public state = 'Open';
    public workOrders$ = this.subjects$.asObservable().pipe(map(orders => {
        return orders.filter(f => f.State == this.state)
    }));
}
```

and the HTML for the tr that is being repeated is

```
<tr *ngFor="let order of workOrders$ | async">
```

and the HTML for the input field for the state

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="state" />
```

On initial load, this correctly filters all the work orders by state, but whenever `this.state` changes, I want to have that pipe refilter the array to update the table. What's the best practice for accomplishing this kind of task? I don't want to mutate the subject because I need to keep the original dataset for when the filter is changed again.

Comment: How is `state` going to be changed? Is it from an input field?

Comment: Yes, sorry it's tied to an input field. I will add that to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the rxjs [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) function and have an observable track the need to recompute:

```
private subject$ = new BehaviorSubject([])
public state = 'Open';
public stateSubject = new BehaviorSubject(this.state);

public workOrders$ = combineLatest(
    this.subjects$,
    this.stateSubject,
    (orders, state) => {
        return orders.filter(f => f.State == state)
    }
);
```

And then on your input:

```
<input type="text" (ngModelChange)="stateSubject.next($event)" [(ngModel)]="state" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `state` was from an input field, which means (assuming the `FormsModule` is imported, which it should be considering the `ngModel`) we can get that value as an Observable.

You can use `switchMap` to subscribe to one Observable, map its emissions to a second Observable, and have the resulting Observable emit values from the second Observable until the first Observable emits again (you *switch* to the new Observable).

You can get the Observable of value changes from your form control a number of different ways depending on how the form is set up, or even just using a `(keyup)` binding. With no
`ngForm` declared in the template attached to the control, you can just query the `ngModel` via template binding:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="state" #value="ngModel"/>
```

then in your component:

class Component {

```
@ViewChild('value') value: NgModel;

//filled with a http call to a webservice
private subject = new BehaviorSubject([])

public state = 'Open'; // This remains as a component property, but we don't need it for the Observable stream as we'll get the value changes Observable from the form control.

public workOrders = this.subject.asObservable().pipe(
    switchMap(this.value.valueChanges),
    withLatestFrom(this.subject),
    map([inputValue, orders] => {
        return orders.filter(f => f.State === inputValue.value)
    }));
}
```

You could also separately manage the subscription from both the http call and the input value changes, but that's no fun.

#### However...

As you can see, the above gets a little complicated; we need `withLatestFrom` to keep the value of the http call, which I'm assuming is static once received. Since you're using the `async` pipe in the markup to subscribe to and call the Observable, it might be a better design choice to just filter that result with another pipe!

```
@Pipe({name: 'filterState'})
  export class FilterStatePipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(value: YourTypeHere[], state: string) {
          return value.filter(s => s.State === state);

      }
}
```

Then declare it in your module and use it in your markup like so:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="state" />

<tr *ngFor="let order of workOrders$ | async | filterState:state">
```

The `async` unwraps the Observable for you, then your custom pipe will filter that value based on the value of `state`. When `state` changes, the pipe should be re-run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a subscription to changes in the input value
This can be done by either converting the form (Assuming the input field is within a form) into a reactive form, or calling a function whenever the input value changes
More information on reactive forms can be found [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/) 
I will go over the second and easiest method:
**HTML**

```
<input type="text" (ngModelChange)="dataChanged()" [(ngModel)]="state" />
```

**TS**

```
class Component {
//filled with a http call to a webservice
private subject$ = new BehaviorSubject([])
public state = 'Open';
public allorders
//Variable to hold all the subjects before applying any filter
this.subjects$.asObservable().subscribe( val => {
    this.allorders = val
  })
}

dataChanged(){
    this.allorders.filter(f => f.State == this.state)
  }));
}
```